# Maui.Audio System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: android, maui

I need to play audio file from external storage on Android. When I try to run an audio file I get an error System.IO.FileNotFoundException.

I've tried:

```
public IAudioPlayer? audioPlayer;
public async void PlaySong()
{
    if (audioPlayer == null)
    {
        audioPlayer = AudioManager.Current.CreatePlayer(await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("filesystem:///storage/emulated/0/Music/mymusic.mp3"));

        audioPlayer.Play();
    }
```

also its dont work, if I specify the path in the form: "/storage/..." or "file:///storage...". It's only work if i put the file in project resources path, but i need to work with external storage. In androidmanifest.xml i have:

```
<application... android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" .../>   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: `OpenAppPackageFileAsync` is for files that are embedded within the app package

Answer (score 1):

You can not use the method   `FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync` to get the local media. Files that were added to the project with the Build Action of MauiAsset can be opened with this method. .NET MAUI projects will process any file in the Resources\Raw folder as a MauiAsset.

Besides, if you want to get the local media you can use the [MediaElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/mediaelement?tabs=android).

Local media can be played from the following sources:

1. A resource embedded in the platform application, using the embed://
   URI scheme.
2. Files that come from the app's local filesystem, using the
   filesystem:// URI scheme.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but mediaelement does not suit me. How can I play audio from an external storage using maui.audio?

Comment: The `Plugin.Maui.Audio` package belongs to the third party. You can check this GitHub content about [Plugin.Maui.Audio](https://github.com/jfversluis/Plugin.Maui.Audio) for more information.